# Distribute IPA - Why keep getting private keys not installed error when distributing apps with enterprise options?

Tags: app-store, private-key, ipa, enterprise

I want to ask about distributing IPA in an enterprise program. What have I done:

```
1. Create a new certificate and private key (the type is ios distribution)
2. upload the certificate in the account for the apple company program website
3. archive my application with xcode 11
4. download renewed apple WWDR certificate
```

When I want to distribute IPA in enterprise mode, I get an error: "`my company has one IOS Distribution certificate but the private key is not installed. Contact the author of this certificate for a copy of the private key`. But actually the computer used to create the certificate and the one used to upload the ipa enterprise are the same (in the keychain already exist).

Can anyone help me with my problem or any suggestion ? Thank you in advance before.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

1. Create a provisioning profile
2. Link profile with certificate
3. Add a profile name
4. Re-upload your application by manual signing and select the profile you created earlier (note : the solution still not possible to auto mode)

Answer (score 1):

Does you app BitCode = NO, if you can change that to YES, then there's another choice `Automatic manage signing`, which can distribute app success.

It's maybe a apple bug, not sure yet.